# Fix addJavascriptInterface Security Message on Play Store

Tags: javascript, android, webview, interface, android-webview

I've an old app with min API level 14+.
Play Store is complaining that I've a security flaw
using addJavascriptInterface method. Android studio reports:

```
WebView.addJavascriptInterface should not be called with minSdkVersion < 17 for security reasons: JavaScript can use reflection to manipulate application...
```

Will console message disappear if I change min SDK to 18+? (I can't add SSL support). Have you any suggestion for a quick fix (it's not my fault, but the Play Store is saying that I have few days to fix.).